# What is this story describing?

Tags: story, knowledge

You sit in an open space with many others.
You tremble with fear as you hear It approach from behind.
You hear the terrible ominous sound, rhythmic and monotonous 
and yet seeming to build in a crescendo of anticipation.
Suddenly It is upon you; your breath ceases and muscles quiver
as you wait to hear the sound, the verdict, your judgment.
God or Devil?
A pause, a hesitation, as It weighs your odds.
You both feel and hear your sentence as the source of the sound 
calls out "Devil" and at once you sigh in relief.
You relax your muscles and a smile creeps on your face,
as you look to your left and witness the fates of your neighbors.
Your joy is short-lived; It will return, It always does.
Searching for the one God.
A God to quickly combat It or slowly supplant It. 
And so it goes, forever.

Can you determine what this passage is describing? As always, a correct response will not only provide an answer, but also an explanation of how the various elements in the story make sense in the context of that answer. Hope you enjoy!

Comment: Some images that popped into my head while reading this were being a blade of grass waiting for a lawnmower and being one of the lines on the face of a clock.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Haha this one was great, I love it!

The answer is

> You are a player in a game of Duck Duck Goose!

You sit in an open space with many others. You tremble with fear as you hear It approach from behind.

> Duck Duck Goose is played with people sitting in a circle facing each other while someone walks around behind them tapping them on the head.

You hear the terrible ominous sound, rhythmic and monotonous and yet seeming to build in a crescendo of anticipation.

> The person who is "It" says "Duck" as they tap each person on the head, usually in a pretty consistent rhythm, but the longer they say "Duck", the more people anticipate the inevitable "Goose".

Suddenly It is upon you; your breath ceases and muscles quiver as you wait to hear the sound, the verdict, your judgment. God or Devil? A pause, a hesitation, as It weighs your odds. You both feel and hear your sentence as the source of the sound calls out "Devil" and at once you sigh in relief.

> In this case Devil = Duck and God = Goose. You have just been passed over as a Duck and will not have to chase the person who is "It".

You relax your muscles and a smile creeps on your face, as you look to your left and witness the fates of your neighbors. Your joy is short-lived; It will return, It always does. Searching for the one God.

> Everybody's sitting in a circle, and the game typically goes clockwise, so the people to your left are next to get tapped on the head.

A God to quickly combat It or slowly supplant It.

> When the person who is "It" chooses, they tap the next person on the head and shout "GOOSE!" The person who was tapped has to get up and chase the person who was "It". If they catch them before the person who is "It" gets around the circle and sits in their spot, they can sit back down (quickly combat it), but if they're too slow, they become "It" (slowly supplant It).

And so it goes, forever.

> Games of Duck Duck Goose traditionally continue for the rest of eternity. When the participants have succumbed due to lack of sustenance and rest, their spirits continue the game for all time, trapped forever in a vicious loop.

Comment: Correct!! I'm glad you enjoyed it. What would you say gave it away?

Comment: @NeedAName I don't know that it "gave it away", but the line I focused on was the rhythm line, with some help from the context given by the Devil/God selection. I might have just been lucky that my mind jumped to the correct answer, but once I had it, the rest of the riddle fell into place pretty easily.

Comment: @NeedAName For me it was the god or devil part.  I already figured it had to be something minor like a game.  It was clear that they were waiting to be picked for something and didn't know when it would happen, only one thing came to mind.